# Chrome shows "aw snap" message after windows update

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-update

I have some unknown problem with chrome.
Today I have been updated my windows 10 after I did not about 2-3 months.
Before the update, chrome worked fine, but now no matter what I'm trying to do "aw snap" message is displaying.

When I browse other browsers such edge everything works fine.

Things I tried already:
1. Reinstall chrome
2. Uninstall the last update of windows
3. Clear chrome cache
4. Run chrome as admin
5. Restart my PC

Nothing worked and I did not find any support about it on the internet.

**Edit:**

Here more information:
 1. The update is: KB2267602 (Definition 1.291.2277.0)
 2. Chrome version is: 73.0.3683.103
 3. I have tried also to delete this folder: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Comment: If you back up your current Chrome user profile, delete the folder and allow Chrome to create a fresh profiles does the behavior still happen?  Which update did you install, you need to provide specifics, otherwise, we cannot help.  What version of Chrome, have you attempted to upgrade by reinstalling chrome?   Do not reply to this comment, with a comment, instead submit an edit to your question.

Comment: `1.3.34.7` isn't the build information for Chrome.  That is the build information for the Google updater.

Comment: What about now?

Answer (score -1):

*"Aw snap"* message can happen because of some *extensions tools, anti-virus software or firewall.* And disabing them may resolve it. check out this link:
https://smallbusiness.chron.com/fix-aw-snap-chrome-71328.html

Comment: I cannot get into chrome://extensions/ because it keeps showing me "aw snap" msg. Is there another way to disable all extensions?